# WP7 Finding a ContextMenu's owner

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu

I am dynamically populating the contents of a `StackPanel` in my application by reading an XML file. Each child of the `StackPanel` is itself another `StackPanel` which contains different `UIElement` objects. The reason for the nested `StackPanel` design is because I want to associate one of 3 different `ContextMenu`s with of these child `StackPanel`s.

So the structure looks like this:

```
  ---- StackPanel parent
       |
       ---- StackPanel child
       |    |
       |    ---- TextBlock
       |
       ---- StackPanel child
       |    |
       |    ---- TextBox
       |
       ---- StackPanel child
       |    |
       |    ---- Image
       |
       .
       .
       .
```

For each `StackPanel` child I'm choosing from amongst 3 `ContextMenu`s and attaching them as follows:

```
var stackPanels = parentStackPanel.Children.OfType<StackPanel>();

for( int i = 0; i < stackPanels.Count(); ++i ) {
  if( someCondition ) {
    ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu( stackPanels.ElementAt( i ), MyContextMenu1 );

  } else if( someOtherCondition ) {
    ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu( stackPanels.ElementAt( i ), MyContextMenu2 );

  } else {
    ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu( stackPanels.ElementAt( i ), MyContextMenu3 );

  }
}
```

All `MenuItem`s under all 3 `ContextMenu`s have the same `Click` handler.

Now, finally, the question: How do I determine which `StackPanel` child's `ContextMenu` was invoked and clicked? Inspecting the sender object within the click handler in the debugger shows that a `ContextMenu` has an `internal` `DependencyObject` named `Owner` which contains a reference to the `StackPanel`, this is exactly what I want but of course, I can't access it in code that way.

I could solve the problem by adding a `MouseLeftButtonDown` handler to each child `StackPanel`, saving the one that was last selected and then retrieving this within the `ContextMenu` handler but this solution feels a little ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast the `sender` as a `UIElement` in the click event handler you should be able to get at whatever you need to identify the actual item which was clicked.

```
(sender as UIElement).Property
```

Alternatively cast as a DependencyObject (if possible) and use that to walk the visual Tree:

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((sender as DependencyObject))
```

Comment: I tried that in the debugger watch window and got an error stating that UIElement does not have a Name property

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry, `Name` was just an example and will only be relevant if you'd specified the name of the object. Have also expanded answer with other alternative.

Comment: Ok, that does seem to work (there is a typo in your edit, the class name should be `VisualTreeHelper`). I abandoned my original approach because it had an additional flaw in it, you cannot attach the same context menu object to multiple parents. So now I'm just building the context menu on the fly.