# how to get parent name of a context menu item?

Tags: windows-phone-7, contextmenu, sender

I'm trying to get the parent name of a context menu item.

So I tried something like this on menuItem_click :

```
Button clikance = (Button)sender;
string ladyGaga = Convert.ToString(clikance.Content);
```

But it didn't work (invalid cast exception). thx for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have use a different approach for getting the sender button of my context menu. i have made an event on the "hold_click"

where i have get back the content of the button in a public string

```
private void GestureListener_DoubleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Button clikance = (Button)sender;
    ButtonEnvoyeur = Convert.ToString(clikance.Content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the debugger at the point where the exception is raised, you'll see that **sender** isn't a `Button`, so trying to do an explicit cast to `Button` will obviously throw an `InvalidCastException`.

You can use the `VisualTreeHelper` to walk up the tree from your actual sender to the `Button` element:

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((sender as DependencyObject));
```

**UPDATE:** In your instance **sender** is the `MenuItem` in the `ContextMenu`. You can get to the parent `ContextMenu` from the `MenuItem` by using the `VisualTreeHelper`, but unfortunately, `ContextMenu` does not expose any public members that enable you to access the owner; the `Owner` property is internal. You could get the source code for the Toolkit and expose the `Owner` property as publi instead, or use a completely different approach.

Have you thought of using an MVVM framework (such as [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)) to wire up commands to these context menu items? Your current approach is very fragile and will break as soon as you change the visual tree. If you used commands, you could pass any additional information that you need for processing via the command parameter.

Comment: well i have try to follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx, since i didnt knew the visualtreeHelper good but VS2010 dont recognize some of the methods describe..

Comment: Because that documentation refers specifically to .NET Framework 4, but development for Windows Phone 7 uses Silverlight (it's actually a modification of Silverlight 3). This page gives the documentation for `VisualTreeHelper` as supported by Silverlight: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=VS.95).aspx. The whit eon blue phone icon indicates supprot for WP7.

Comment: my problem looks like his one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560244/wp7-finding-a-contextmenus-owner   but even with the good answer i dont get how to do it

Comment: i have try 
            UIElement brut = (UIElement)sender;
            DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(brut);

            while (parent as Button == null)
            {
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
            }       but i still get a exception error

Comment: You need to set the debugger to break on all exceptions and look to see what the type is for the **sender** parameter that you are trying to cast (assuming that's the line that is throwing the exception).

Comment: well, when i put a breakpoint on the contextmenuItem, i can retrieve my button as the "_owner" but when i do this UIElement myContextMenuItem = (UIElement)sender;

            DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(myContextMenuItem);

            for (;;)
            {
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
                if (parent as Button != null )
               break;
            }      he dont find any button and throw an exception when the parent become null after being a stackpanel, a canvas etc...

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more complete solution for you based on the additional information you've provided. Hope this helps.

Comment: first thx for u help. i have try ur updated solution but my VS2010 dont recognize nor ".owner" and ".ParentMenuBase" as definition. my goal is to retrieve the content of the button for deleting him in the database and then refresh the listbox so i think i dont need MVVM in this case.

Comment: My mistake; I missed that both of those properties are actually internal. I've updated my answer again, but I don't think there's an easy solution without either modifying the Toolkit code (very easy) or switching to MVVM.

Comment: hum i dont have enough skill for doing that... and what is your opinion on getting on "hold_event" the sender button ? maybe is it possible to get the content in a string value

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tag property of the MenuItem to retrieve your Button :

```
// Object creation
Button myButtonWithContextMenu = new Button();
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem aMenuItem = new MenuItem 
{
    Header = "some action",
    Tag = myButtonWithContextMenu, // tag contains the button
};

// Events handler
aMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(itemClick);

private void itemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Sender is the MenuItem
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;

    // Retrieve button from tag
    Button myButtonWithContextMenu = menuItem.Tag as Button;
    (...)         
}
```

Alex.